# Devcot in Docker Mailserver not starting

Tags: docker, mail-server

I have downloaded the container "docker-mailserver" and I am launching it via Portainer stack. When the stack executes, it always gets stuck with a dovecot error. The below happens inside the container. What can I do?

```
[   INF   ]  Welcome to docker-mailserver 11.3.0
[   INF   ]  Initializing setup
[   INF   ]  Checking configuration
[   INF   ]  Configuring mail server
[ WARNING ]  You need at least one mail account to start Dovecot (120s left for account creation before shutdown)
[ WARNING ]  You need at least one mail account to start Dovecot (110s left for account creation before shutdown)
```

....
....

My stack is below:

```
services:
  mailserver:
    image: docker.io/mailserver/docker-mailserver:latest
    container_name: mailserver
    # Provide the FQDN of your mail server here (Your DNS MX record should point to this value)
    hostname: mail.domain.win
    ports:
      - "28:25"
      - "590:587"
      - "996:993"
    volumes:
    - /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-14a35ebc-6358-492c-af84-4e920f0c55bc/Docker/volumes/ajmail/mail-data/:/var/mail/
    - /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-14a35ebc-6358-492c-af84-4e920f0c55bc/Docker/volumes/ajmail/mail-state/:/var/mail-state/
    - /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-14a35ebc-6358-492c-af84-4e920f0c55bc/Docker/volumes/ajmail/mail-logs/:/var/log/mail/
    - /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-14a35ebc-6358-492c-af84-4e920f0c55bc/Docker/volumes/ajmail/config/:/tmp/docker-mailserver/
    - /etc/localtime/:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - ENABLE_SPAMASSASSIN=1
      - SPAMASSASSIN_SPAM_TO_INBOX=1
      - ENABLE_CLAMAV=1
      - ENABLE_FAIL2BAN=1
      - ENABLE_POSTGREY=1
    restart: always
  #  stop_grace_period: 1m
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
  #  healthcheck:
  #    test: "ss --listening --tcp | grep -P 'LISTEN.+:smtp' || exit 1"
  #    timeout: 3s
  #    retries: 0
```

Comment: Silly question, but have you defined at least one mail account?

Comment: I havent even gotten to that. This happens at the container launch phase.

Comment: You need to provide it at the time of the container creation, not afterwards via a Terminal 

Comment: How can I provide a mail account when the environment is not even created yet? I think only after the stack has completed by launching the container I can log in via terminal and add stuff. No?

Comment: can so eone explain why my question has been voted down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During container launch, you have to quickly log into the container via SSH and type

```
"setup email add xxx@domain.yyy"
```

(not ./setup.sh as all the documentation tells you!)
Then the container launch will continue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).